# Как оптимизировать код objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, изображения, оптимизация

Проблема заключается в том, что моё приложение жрёт много оперативной памяти (300 мб). На 4s приложение вылетает, на остальных, кроме 6 и 6+  виснет. В приложении много картинок и таблиц с картинками. Мне нужно снизить нагрузку на оперативную память, как-то иначе грузить картинки с сервера.
Вот код, как сейчас реализована загрузка картинок:

```
NSString *filePath1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",responsePhotos[0]];
NSURL *imgurl=[NSURL URLWithString:filePath1];
dispatch_queue_t queue =     dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
   NSData *dataimage1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgurl];
   UIImage *imim1 = [UIImage imageWithData:dataimage1];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (imim1==nil) {
            cell.imgauto1.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_a.gif"];
        }else{
            cell.imgauto1.image=imim1;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы очень плохо все делаете,так нельзя делать, делать загрузку картинки, потом сразу же ее в ячейку ложить. Для загрузки изображений и их кеширования используйте [SDWebImageCash](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), очень простая библиотека, и очень хорошо написана, либо же, напишите свое кеширование, но записывать картинки вручную, тем более как я понимаю в методе делегата таблицы, это очень плохо. Можно еще использовать CoreData, для хранения тех же изображений. Теперь по поводу архитектуры, и как правильно сделать, вы загружаете изображения в методе создания ячеек - убираем это от туда, это метод только для передачи в ячейки уже готовой информации. В методе viewDidLoad вы должны загрузить часть изображений, и уже передать их скачанные в ячейку, и назначить. Почему часть, потому что качать например 100 картинок, это значит что пользователь будет все это время ждать их загрузки, тоже плохо, используйте [infinityscroll и pulltorefresh](https://github.com/samvermette/SVPullToRefresh), принцип такой:дойдя до конца таблицы, 10 ячейки, например, начните загрузку еще 10 штук, и потом обновите таблицу.

Comment: Огромное Вам СПАСИБО!!! Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: Обращайтесь! Еще остались вопросы?